# MySQL: Use index in background query

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, database-indexes

I'm using MySQL 5.7.10.

I'm checking a new query for an audit report.

I'll execute it in a simple background Unix process, which invoke mysql from the console.

To check the query, I use a worksheet in HeidiSQL.

The table is:

```
CREATE TABLE `services` (
`assigned_id` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`service_id` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
`name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
...
`audit_insert` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
...
INDEX `idx_audit_insert` (`audit_insert`),
...
```

);

The simple worksheet is:

```
SET @numberOfMonths:=6;
SET @today:=CURRENT_TIMESTAMP();
SET @todaySubstractnumberOfMonths=TIMESTAMP( date_sub(@today, interval @numberOfMonths MONTH) );

EXPLAIN SELECT service_id from services where audit_insert between @todaySubstractnumberOfMonths and @today;
```

The explain output for that query is:
id,select_type,table,partitions,type,possible_keys,key,key_len,ref,rows,filtered,Extra
1,SIMPLE,services,[all partitions],***ALL,idx_audit_insert***,,,,47319735,21.05,Using where

So, index 'idx_audit_insert' is not used.

If I change the query to:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT service_id where audit_insert between '2020-01-01 00:00:00' and '2020-03-10 23:59:59';
```

The output is:
id,select_type,table,partitions,type,possible_keys,key,key_len,ref,rows,filtered,Extra
1,SIMPLE,tdom_transitos,[all partitions],***range,idx_audit_insert,idx_audit_insert***,4,,4257192,100.00,Using index condition

Now, the index is used and the rows value is dramatically reduced.

So, my questions are:

- How can I force the variables to be timestamp? Is there any wrong in my worksheet?

or maybe

- How can I use the index (trying to avoid hints like USE INDEX, FORCE INDEX...)?

Thanks a lot.

(EDIT: I copy the same question in dbastackexchange. Maybe is more properly for that forum).

Comment: *How can I force the variables to be timestamp?* Try explicitly `where audit_insert between CAST(@todaySubstractnumberOfMonths AS DATETIME) and CAST(@today AS DATETIME);` *How can I use the index* You must have data for at least 7-8 years (for 1-month period)...

Comment: @akina, thank you for your suggestion about CAST(), but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Well, maybe it's not the answer I thought I'd find, but it works perfectly.

I have splitted audit_insert field in another one, *audit_insert_datetype*, of DATE type. This field has a new index too.

I have changed the query to execute with this field, and I have tried to force the @... variables to be date type (with current_date and date).

The results: the new index is used and the execution time is dramatically reduced.
Maybe it's bad style, but it works as I need.

Answer (score 0):

All that date arithmetic can be done in SQL.  If you do that, it will use the index.

"Constant" expressions (such as `CURDATE() + INTERVAL 4 MONTH`) are evaluated to a `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP` datatype before starting the query.